# PLL Theory - Laplace Transform

Tags: pll, laplace-transform

[image]

[Design of Analog CMOS inteagrtaed circuits by Razavi]

Can someone explain what Lapalce transform rules states that this is possible? They have a function of excess output phase / excess input phase in s-domain and they say that this can be extended to w_out/w_in since the derivative is a linear operator? How?

Comment: But you should not forget that the given transfer function results from a linearization process and applies under locked conditions only. That means: Both frequencies must not differ too much (frequency difference smaller than the natural PLL frequency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PLL theory, aside from the fact that they're using a linear system approximation.

You have the relationship

$$\frac{\phi_{out}}{\phi_{in}} = H_{cl}(s) \tag 1$$

**By definition**, \$\omega_{out} = \phi_{out} s \$ and \$\omega_{in} = \phi_{in} s\$.

So

$$\frac{\omega_{out}}{\omega_{in}} = \frac{\phi_{out} s}{\phi_{in} s} = \frac{\phi_{out}}{\phi_{in}} = H_{cl}(s) \tag 2$$

QED

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!